# Javascript function is not getting called on OnKeyPress and OnKeyDown event

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to call a function validatQty on onkeypress and onkeydown event of a text. It was working fine when I was just passing event (single parameter) to this function. But when I tried to add a second parameter which I am getting through PHP, the function is not getting called anymore. Where is the error in my following code.

In my PHP File

```
<input type="text" id="txtAnyName" 
       onkeypress='return validateQty(event, <?php echo $data['anyName']; ?>)' 
       onkeydown='return validateQty(event, <?php echo $data['anyName']; ?>)'>
```

**Javascript file**

```
function validateQty(event, anyName) 
{   
    alert(anyName);

    var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;

    if ( key < 48 || key > 57 ) 
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: What your console is saying?

Comment: @DholakiyaAnkit - Nothing

Comment: what alert is saying?

Comment: <?php echo $data['anyName']; ?> is a string right?? shouldnt it be wrapped in quotes or something?? o_O

Comment: @PsychHalf - I had wrapped it in single quotes, but it was not working. Now I have wrapped it in double quotes and it is working.

Comment: @nkp and i should have posted that as an answer,,no reps for me... TwT

Comment: @PsychHalf - I have upvoted you comments :)

Comment: @nkp thanks dude.. well. rep or no rep.. i'm glad i could help someone ^^

Comment: @PsychHalf - Really, you helped me out :) thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you missing double quotes in your function...

```
<input type="text" id="txtAnyName" 
       onkeypress='return validateQty(event, "<?php echo $data['anyName']; ?>")' 
       onkeydown='return validateQty(event, "<?php echo $data['anyName']; ?>")'>
```

here is working example of [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/cinenosa/1/)